# How do I add UIView on UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, xcode6

I wanted to add some labels and textfields on my view and that view should scroll, so I am thinking of putting view on scrollview.

1. I wanted to add some labels and textfields on my view
2. And that view should scroll
3. So I am thinking of putting scrollView
4. And then I wanted to put my view having labels and Textfields
5. Is it possible?

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: Yes whatever you said is possible .Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes i tried.
but it is not scrolling.

Comment: check have u added contentsize for your scrollview.

Comment: Sure you can. Do you want to make this by code or via Interface Builder? Do you want to use autolayout or autoresizing masks?

Comment: @Uma , i have checked it is all correct , the scroll view is bigger than my view size

Comment: @NicolaGiancecchi , i want to make this by Interface Builder.

Comment: Can u post the code.

Comment: put view with labels in scrollview. Scrollview should be less in height than view. View should have height considering all ui cvontrols in it.
should work like this

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora , let me try this one. and then i will tell u.

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora ,  it didn't worked.

Comment: @Uma ,1. I have taken UIScrollview than a UIView and put some Labels on it.
2. Then I have created IBOutlets of ScrollView and View, Also wrote Scrollview Delegate
3. Then Trying to run it, but it is not scrolling.

Comment: @user3427565 ok ..take view add scrollview then add your uilabels .

Comment: @Uma , done -- next?

Answer (score 2):

Please check scrollview property Bounces Vertically is checked or not if not check it
[image]

Comment: soo many thanks to you.. actually "Bounce Vertically" check box is not clicked.. thats why it is not scrolling.. 
i am beginner so please don't  mind i have made silly mistake.
"Stumble and learning.."

Answer (score 0):

May be, your content is less, than `ScrollView`, that's why scrolling is disabled

Comment: i have checked it is all correct , the scroll view is bigger than my view size

Answer (score 0):

Put view with labels in scrollview. Scrollview should be less in height than view. View should have height considering all ui cvontrols in it. should work like this

Comment: share xib/storyboard screenshots

Comment: i don't know how to post image , could i mail you?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your scroll view height is not greater than view its content size has to be greater as all people says. You get confused between content size and scroll view height.
Meas using nib suppose your scroll view height is 300 and when you use the code content size should be greater than 480 so it will be scroll-able on iPhone 4 size device who's height is 480

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your constraints are well defined, first check these steps:

- Make sure your base view is a UIView
- Put into a UIScrollView and add constraints to the edges of UIView
- Put into the scrollview a UIView and add constraints to the edges of the scrollview. I call this "content view".
- You should assign a width to the content view. I usually set the width of the content view equal to the width of the scrollview.
- Put your labels/views/images/whatever into the content view and use autolayout constraints to resize them automatically to fit the target screen.

Please consider that:

- Your scrollview **must** always have a height, fixed or dynamic. In order to avoid errors with autolayout, consider that:

  - the last element on the bottom of the content view must always have a constraint to the bottom edge of the scrollview, **or**
  - the content view must have a fixed height
- If the height of your content view is less than the height of the scrollview, the view will not scroll. You should add more views or more margin to the bottom constraint of the content view.